# How to trace map region while scrolling Map in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps

I completed to display map view to current location in iPhone with maximize zoom level.

But now i want to trace **any scrolling** in map view to get its visible area.

Is there any Event to do that if Yes then How??

If No the How it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible through mapView's delegate.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    // This method is called whenever the currently displayed map region changes. 
    // During scrolling, this method may be called many times to report updates to the map position. 
    // Therefore, your implementation of this method should be as lightweight as possible to avoid affecting scrolling performance. 
   // *Straight from Apple's documentation

   MKMapRect visibleRect = [mapView visibleMapRect];
}
```

Comment: Oops...It's not working..!!!I just pasted this coding my implementation and set debugger..And it is not working..

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is not working? Did you set the delegate of your mapView?

Comment: @Downloadmore it works perfect. Maybe you've forgot to set the `delegate` for the map view. :)